# Does Child Project requires parent project?

Tags: asp.net, iis

In IIS, I have a parent application, say 'AppA' in one of my sites. The URL for this application is similar to http://abc.com/appa. Another application 'AppB' is child of 'AppA' in IIS so that the URL could be like http://abc.com/appa/appb and for AppB to share the configuration of AppA. Apart from that I would like AppA and AppB to remain independent.

Does AppB need to have AppA.dll for it to work

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You just need to set the web.config values to be inherited in AppB.  AppB is just a logical container and has no concept of what AppA is or what it does.

Comment: The exception to this would be if the web.config entries depended on code from AppA. Http Modules, for instance.

Comment: @John Sanders: thats right -- had figured it out and made sure common handlers were moved to library and AppB started working